# Create user account from admin page using react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an admin page written in react and Firebase. In my administration page, I want to create an account for the user (username, email, phone number, address, password). But my code does not work, does not return error.

This is Form create user

```
import { auth, db } from '../../../../../../firebase';
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    phone: '',
    address: '',
    error: null,
};

const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
    [propertyName]: value,
});

class FormUser extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
    }
    onSubmit = (event) => {
        const {
            username,
            email,
            password,
            phone,
            address,
        } = this.state;
        auth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(authUser => {
                // Create a user in your own accessible Firebase Database too
                db.doCreateUser(authUser.user.uid, username, email, password, phone, address)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
    render() {
        const {
            username,
            email,
            password,
            phone,
            address,
            error,
        } = this.state;

        return (
           ...
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label">User Name</label>
                    <input className="form-control form-white"
                        type="text"
                        id="username"
                        required
                        placeholder="User Name"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('username', event.target.value))}
                    />
                    <input ... email />
                    <input ... phone />
                    <input ... address />
                    <input ... password />
                </div>      
            </form>

            <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button className="btn btn-block btn-gradient waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" disabled={isInvalid}>Create User</button>
                {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FormUser;
```

This is db.js

```
import { db } from './firebase';
export const doCreateUser = (id, username, email, phone, address, password) =>
  db.ref(`users/${id}`).set({
    username,
    email,
    phone,
    address,
    password
  });
```

Version:
"firebase": "^5.5.0",
"react": "^16.5.1",

Comment: Are you sure that you have enabled simple email / password users in firebase ?

Comment: Yes. Because I also have a method for registering an account for admin and registering successfully.
export const doCreateAdmin = (id, username, email) =>
  db.ref(`admin/${id}`).set({
    username,
    email,
  });

Comment: Does the onSubmit run ? Can you try binding it in the constructor with `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)` ?

Comment: Thanks all. I moved "Create User" button before </form>. It's working.